# How reliable is the Elbow curve in finding K in K-Means?

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis, k-means, word2vec

So I was trying to use the Elbow curve to find the value of optimum 'K' (number of clusters) in K-Means clustering.

The clustering was done for the average vectors (using Word2Vec) of a text column in my dataset (1467 rows). But looking at my text data, I can clearly find more than 3 groups the data can be grouped into.

I read the reasoning is to have a small value of k while keeping the Sum of Squared Errors (SSE) low. Can somebody tell me how reliable the Elbow Curve is? 
Also if there's something I'm missing.

Attaching the Elbow curve for reference. I also tried plotting it up to 70 clusters, exploratory.[image].

[image]

Comment: Two people looking at the same elbow curve might come to different conclusions about the optimal number of clusters. An alternative measure is average silhouette width. There are numerous other measures. In R, you can use the NbClust package and its NbClust function. It will calculate up to 30 measures and give you a majority vote on the recommended number of clusters. (By default, it calculates 26 measures, because 4 are computationally expensive.) Use the fviz_nbclust function from the factoextra package to visualize results. Generally, I'd look at context, not only statistical measures.

Comment: @Wolf Thanks for the insights. Silhouette score helped me here,( glad I posted this ), guess these should be looked upon as the heuristics they are!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "elbow" is not even well defined so how can it be reliable?

You can "normalize" the values by the expected dropoff from splitting the data into k clusters and it will become a bit more readable.
For example, the Calinski and Harabasz (1974) [variance ratio criterion](http://docode.techyoung.cn/calinski_harabasz/chi.pdf). It is essentially a rescaled version that makes *much* more sense.